# CV.imwrite is returning a black square

Tags: python, opencv

My simple resizing code is returning a black square in the desired size. This is obviously some rookie error but I can't work out for the life of me what it is.

Has nothing to do with compression as I have tried with a blank image and the same result occurs.

```py
    img = cv2.imread('imageToSave.jpg')
    # percent of original size
    width = 28
    height = 28
    dim = (width, height)
    res = cv2.resize(img, dim)
    cv2.imwrite('imageToSave.jpg',res)
```

Ideally the result would be a rescaled version of the 'imageToSave file

Comment: Your code works for me (except that 28x28 is the final size in pixels, not percent as your comment seems to suggest).

Comment: That is odd, the percentage comment is a relic from a different attempt to solve this problem. Mabye it's todo with channels?

Comment: ImageToSave has an alpha channel, does that effect things, if so how should I remove it?

Comment: I don't see how a jpg can have an alpha channel. Is your input image a tiff or png (and do you really open imageToSave.jpg ?). Anyway, one good thing to do in these situations is `print(img.shape, img.dtype)`. Shape will be (orig_height, orig_width, nb_channels), so you'll see if it has an alpha. The dtype is also important, it is uint8 on my image (i.e. standard RGB). Then `print(img)` to see if it has only zeros in input and/or output.

Comment: I'm getting the correct result running your code, is there any traceback error?

Answer (score 1):

I may be too down to earth but did you try to display your picture after the reading and after your resize instead of saving it locally?

These two step will locate the issue, and you'll fix it quick i think :)